# Failure to launch app from dock on iPad with PadOS13

Tags: ios, dock, ipados, ipados13

I have a weird problem. My iPad app on iOS12 works fine, but on padOS13 it shows problems.

On the simulator, it won't show in the dock.
On the device, it shows in the dock, but tapping there won't launch it.

I've put breakpoints into the app delegate methods for applicationWillEnterForeground, applicationDidBecomeActive, etc. and on iOS 12 they get called. On 13 they don't.

I'm not (yet) using Scenes, I'm still reading up on them. But I have a window property on the app delegate, so I should not require Scenes at this time. At least from what I've read about opting out of Scenes.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. Tapping on the app in the dock results in no messages to the app to activate. I can tap on the app icon and it will reopen, but the dock icon is unresponsive. Yet it works fine on 12. This is very frustrating!

Any advice?

Comment: I think this is a bug in iPadOS. I've been having this issue since the early beta versions and it is still a problem with 13.1.1. Tapping the icon in the dock doesn't launch the app at all. Just tap on the main app icon.

Comment: I just updated to 13.1.2 and I can tap on the icon now. But I know it worked temporarily when I updated to 13.1.1.

Comment: @rmaddy, I'm already on 13.1.2. Sigh. I've tried rebooting and the dock will work to launch the app, but when I put a new build on the iPad, it fails again. I don't know if it's because it's a debug build or not. Also not sure if it will fail when it gets to my users. Very frustrating, Apple!

Comment: I’m having this issue as well and am pulling my hair out over it. In my case I can see it in the dock on the simulator and it launches OK there, but on a real device, no luck.

Comment: I’m having a similar issue on iPadOS 13.1.2.  However, in my case it is only when the app is shown in the “Recent Apps” section on the right of the dock.  If I drag the icon into the main section of the dock, it always seems to launch when tapped.

Comment: As per this link - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122909 In last comment it says it is resolved on version 13.2, but I am able to reproduce this on 13.2 iPad OS version as well.

Answer (score 4):

I’m seeing this on all sorts of different apps (running iPadOS 13.1.2) so doN’t take it personally immediately as I think it’s a bug in the OS. Thought I was going crazy at first and not pressing the icon, then thought it was an app issue, until I realised it was happening to 1st and 3rd party apps. Launching from the icon on the home screen works, and reboot seems to sort the problem out for a short time, but it soon starts failing to launch the apps again.

Comment: Did you report the bug to Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Just installed padOS 13.1.3 and the problem is resolved.

Comment: Argh, nope it was just the reboot that made it work for a bit. Now, after installing another beta version, it fails to launch from the dock again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue iPadOS 13.1.3 - quite a few other small issues have arisen as well - hoping for new update with remedies.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't use answers for commenting. When you have enough reputation then you'll be able to comment on questions.